# MYSQL digit filtering query on text field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table which looks like this (simplified):

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║  Product     ║ Tags    ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ Product1     ║a,1-5,b  ║
║  2 ║ Product2     ║a,6-12,d ║
║  3 ║ Product3     ║a,20-30,c║
║  4 ║ Product4     ║b,5-55,a ║
╚════╩══════════════╩═════════╝
```

The query I'm struggling with should return the results based on `Tags` column.

**Example**

Should return all products that have the `a` tag (no matter of the position determined with `,` character) with number scope from `6-21` for the second tag, which represents the years of the ones potentially interested into product.

I'm clueless on how to do this.

Comment: Your problem is storing multiple values in a single string column.  You should work on fixing that.

Comment: The specified duplicate is quite on-target and I upvoted Bill Karwin's answer a long, long time ago.  However, it really is not a duplicate of this question (perhaps a duplicate of what this question *should* be, but not this question).

Answer (score 3):

You should not store multiple values in a string column.  It is wrong, wrong, wrong.  SQL has a great way to store lists.  It is called a *table*, which has rows and columns for each value.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad decisions.  For those purposes, MySQL has a convenient function, [`find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
where find_in_set('a', tags) > 0
```

Your effort should go into fixing the data model, rather than trying to work around it.

Comment: _SQL has a great way to store lists. It is called a table..._ +1 :)

Comment: *Other peoples' really, really, really bad decisions.* +1

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice, but as you said, sometimes we're stuck with people's bad decisions and this table design is one of those. However, I gotta stick with it for now. When it comes to the query where clause you suggest to use, it returns all the rows that have a tag, not taking the second part (the age range) into consideration. What's difference between this one and the wildcard search `WHERE 'a,%' OR '%,a'` when it comes to results?